# testing mailers in rspec

Tags: actionmailer, rspec2

Is there no simple way to do the equivalent of `response.should render_template(:foo)` in a mailer spec?  Here's what I want to do:

> mail.should render_template(:welcome)

Is that so much to ask?  Am I stuck in the dark ages of heredocs or manually reading fixtures in to match against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [email-spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec).  It doesn't have the exact syntax but it is used for testing various aspects of sending emails.

Comment: Actually... close enough, I guess. Your answer addresses the title of my question, just not exactly what I was looking for (was looking for a `render_template` assertion helper in mailer specs).  But this is still good enough to get most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
    # IMPORTANT!
    # must copy https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/spec/support/helpers/next_instance_of.rb
    it 'renders foo_mail' do
      allow_next_instance_of(described_class) do |mailer|
        allow(mailer).to receive(:render_to_body).and_wrap_original do |m, options|
          expect(options[:template]).to eq('foo_mail')

          m.call(options)
        end
      end

      body = subject.body.encoded
    end
```